# Join on a comma-deli string column - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a code in the stored procedure and it needs to join on a comma-deli string column. I tried but it is failing to recognized by sql server. Please let me know the right approach for it. Here is the code from the sproc:

```
INSERT INTO CPE_EXT_Downloaded (FileName, LocalServerID, WaitingACK, CreationDate, FileSize, MD5, ErrorMsgTime, LocationID, OfferID)  
    SELECT 
       cip.FileName, LS.LocalServerID, cip.WaitingACK, cip.CreationDate, 
       cip.FileSize, cip.MD5, cip.ErrorMsgTime, ILV.LocationID, cip.OfferID   
    FROM 
       @WorkSet ws       
    INNER JOIN 
       CPE_IncentiveDLBuffer_Pending cip WITH (NOLOCK) ON cip.POID = ws.POID
    INNER JOIN 
       CPE_IncentiveLocationsView AS ILV WITH (NOLOCK) ON ILV.IncentiveID = cip.OfferID 
    INNER JOIN 
       LocalServers AS LS WITH (NOLOCK) ON LS.LocationID = ILV.LocationID  
    CROSS APPLY on 
       dbo.split(cip.LocationGroups, ',') AS ST ON st.items = ILV.LocationID
    WHERE
       LS.MustIPL = 0
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. See [How Do I Format My Code Blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to learn how.

Comment: There **must NOT** be a `on` immediately after the `CROSS APPLY` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered doing a regular join instead?

```
        FROM @WorkSet ws       
        INNER JOIN CPE_IncentiveDLBuffer_Pending cip WITH (NOLOCK)
        on cip.POID = ws.POID
        inner join  CPE_IncentiveLocationsView as ILV WITH (NOLOCK)
        on ILV.IncentiveID= cip.OfferID and
           ','+cip.LocationGroups+',' like '%,'+ILV.LocationId+',%'
        Inner Join LocalServers as LS with (NoLock) on LS.LocationID=ILV.LocationID
```

Comment: You'll need some wildcards: `like '%,'+ILV.LocationId+',%'`

Comment: @HansKesting . . . Thank you for catching that.